# How do i decrease the size of array?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
    int i=0,pos;
    int *ptr;
    clrscr();
    ptr=(int *)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
    printf("Enter 10 Elements:\n");
    while(i<10)
    {
        scanf("%d",&ptr[i]);
        i++;
    }

    printf("Current Array:\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",ptr[i]);
    }
    printf("Enter the position to be deleted:");
    scanf("%d",&pos);
    for(i=pos;i<10;i++)
    {
        ptr[pos-1]=ptr[pos];
       pos++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t",ptr[i]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Array i enter : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0

> Suppose 4th position has been deleted

Array after deletion: 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 0 0

How can i make the program to print only 9 integers but without decresing the times the loop run.

i.e. without using
`for(i=0;i<9;i++)`

Comment: Why you do not want to decrease to loop size?

Comment: You can hold the current size in one variable,  as you delete a element current size should be decreased by one.

Comment: C has no concept of "empty" elements. If you want to know that only 8 elements of an array that can hold 10 are valid, you have to keep track of that information yourself in another variable.

Comment: What is the objection to using a variable for the number of items in the array, instead of hard coding? If there are 9 elements used in the array, why insist that you iterate to `10`? And there is no point using dynamic allocation at run time, it the size is hard coded at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't allow you to do that. So, alternative is to dynamically allocate an array, put what you want in it, then when you get the size you want, transfer that data to a newly allocated array of the appropriate size and delete the old one.

Comment: Could you please tell how print will be impacted with that?

Comment: class mystring {
private:
  char* c;
  int lnth, capacity;
public:
  mystring();
  ~mystring();
  bool append(char x);
};
We have now declared c to be a pointer to a char, and we have added a new variable, capacity, to keep track of the current length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to keep track of how many elements of the array are being used.

When you start:

```
unsigned num_elements = 10;
int *ptr = malloc(num_elements * sizeof(int));
```

When you delete, do the following as well:

```
--num_elements;
```

When you print:

```
for (unsigned i=0; i<num_elements; ++i) {
    ...
}
```

---

Since you print the array in multiple places in the code, it would be nice to create a small function to do it.

```
void print_array(int *a, unsigned size) {
   if (size == 0) {
      printf("[empty]\n");
      return;
   }

   printf("%d", a[0]);

   for (unsigned i=1; i<size; ++i) {
      printf("\t%d", a[i]);
   }

   printf("\n");
}

print_array(ptr, num_elements);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your questions refers to 2 issues here:

1. Deleting an element of an dynamically allocated array
2. Printing values of an dynamically allocated array without adjusting `for` loop parameters

1)

```
for(i=pos;i<10;i++)
{
   ptr[pos-1]=ptr[pos];
   pos++;
}
```

Does not decrease the array at all - you just overwrite the particalur position with another element but you still have memory allocated for 10 `int`

One way to reach that would be using `realloc` after you moved the values by to the left beginning at the target element:

```
for (i = pos; i < array_size - 1; i++)
{
   ptr[i] = ptr[i+1];
}

ptr = realloc(ptr, --array_size)
```

To 2)

Simple answer: This wont be possible. When you decrease the size of your array and dont adjust the loop's paramter you will access memory which doesnt belong to the array anymore.

Of course you dont want to adjust every for-loop by hand but you can simplify life if you always remember the array's size, preferably in immediate reference to it within a `struct`:

```
typedef struct
{
   size_t size;
   int *array;
} my_array_t;
```

If you ensure that `size` is properly adjusted everytime you allocate the array's memory (functions are your friend), you can always print the values with:

```
my_array_t a;
a.size = 10;
a.array = malloc(a.size * sizeof(int));

for (i=0; i < a.size; i++)
   // ...
```